# How to filter out array of elements from array of object via rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

i have two arrays my main array is here

```
 let main=[
        { name:'someone',category:[1,45,67]},
        { name:'someone',category:[1,25,127]},
        { name:'someone',category:[1,89,127]}
     ]
```

i want to put filter on it based on **category** and here is array of category which i want from main array

```
   let Categoryfilter=[45,25]
```

and result should be after filter

```
        [
        { name:'someone',category:[1,45,67]},
        { name:'someone',category:[1,25,127]}
        ]
```

Comment: This seems more of ES6 or typescript problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly modified version from rxjs documentation:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source = from([        { name:'someone1',category:[1,45,67]},
        { name:'someone2',category:[1,25,127]},
        { name:'someone3',category:[1,89,127]}]);
let Categoryfilter=[45,25]

const example = source.pipe(
  filter(
    person => 
      !!person.category.find((catnum) => Categoryfilter.includes(catnum))
  )
);

const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val.name));
```

I am not sure, if it is efficient or not.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it but maybe I can give you an idea ?

```
const filteredArray = main.filter(element =>
element.category.some(number => categoryFilter.indexOf(number) > -1))
```

Comment: i want with rxjs

Answer (score -1):

you can use build in filter function

```
const filtered = main.filter(item => item.category.includes(45) || item.category.includes(25));
```